# On some conjectures about an inequality involving different arithmetic functions related to prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization, prime-gaps

I've written the following puzzle about prime numbers. This exercise is thus a curiosity/miscellany about the distribution of prime number $p_k$, that I wondered when I was playing with different arithmetic functions. Thus maybe the inequality is artificious.

For integers $n\geq 1$ in this post we denote the $n$th prime number as $p_n$, $\pi(n)$ is the prime-counting function. And $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ denotes the product of distinct pimes dividing an integer $n>1$, with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$, that is the so-called radical of an integer (see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)).

I've consider integers, or equivalently the indexes of those prime numbers $p_n$, satisfying for some $\epsilon>0$

$$n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}\cdot p_n<\frac{\pi(n)}{\pi(2n)}\cdot\operatorname{rad}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right).\tag{1}$$
Here of course we can write $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ instead of $\sum_{k=1}^n k$.

> **Question.** Prove or refute the following conjectures:
>
> A) *When* $\epsilon =0$ *there are infinitely many integers* $n\geq 1$ (or as you want to see it, the subscripts $n$'s of primes $p_n$) *satisfying the inequality* $(1)$.
>
> B) *If* $n\geq 1$ *is a solution of* $(1)$ *then our real* $0<\epsilon$ *satisfies* $\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$.
>
> **Many thanks.**

In summary I am asking how to attack these exercises involving the inequality. I believe thus that there are solutions only for $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$. About B) of course, if you find counterexamples you can solve the Question invoking those. If A) is very difficult to solve, I should to accept some answer showing what work can be done or a remarkable heuristic/reasoning. Also computational evidence is welcome as attached to your answer or in comments.

Comment: I've added the tags (prime-gaps) because I think that is related. Things that can be useful are that the prime number theorem is equivalent to $p_n\sim n\log n$ as $n\to\infty$, and implies $\frac{\pi(n)}{\pi(2n)}\sim\frac{1}{2}$ as $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the discussion of prime numbers here and the various counting functions is largely a red herring; this is a pure matter of asymptotics and squarefreeness.  Note that since $\gcd(n,n+1)=1$, $\mathrm{rad}(n(n+1)/2)$ is either $\mathrm{rad}(n/2)\mathrm{rad}(n+1)$ or $\mathrm{rad}(n)\mathrm{rad}((n+1)/2)$. But $\mathrm{rad}(n)=n$ if $n$ is squarefree, and it's known that there are infinitely many (in fact, a positive proportion) of consecutive squarefree numbers; see [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59741/are-there-infinitely-many-triples-of-consecutive-square-free-integers) for some discussion and references. Thus, infinitely often you'll have $\mathrm{rad(n(n+1)/2)}=n(n+1)/2$.  From here, the rest is easy asymptotics: as you noted yourself, $\frac{\pi(n)}{\pi(2n)}\to\frac12$, so your RHS is $\Theta(n^2)$ on a set of positive density; since your LHS is $\Theta(n^{(3/2)+\epsilon}\log n)$ then the inequality will hold 'asymptotically' (and therefore infinitely often) for any $\epsilon\lt\frac12$.

OTOH, when $\epsilon=\frac12$ the LHS is $\Theta(n^2\log n)$ and the RHS is (everywhere, not just on a positive-density set) $O(n^2)$ so there can be at most finitely many counterexamples; it shouldn't be hard to find explicit bounds for all of the quantities involved, and from there put a bound on the size of any counterexamples that's within range of easy hand (or computer-aided) checking.

Comment: I accept if in my inequality the presence of some function isn't well motivated (some of my experiments are more artificious than I would like). I also appreciate the criticism because it is a good way for me. 
I have read the answer and I think it is enough (excellent, congratulations!) for me. I have to read it in more detail and study the post of MO. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user243301 I didn't mean to come off too critical; apologies if that was the impression that you got. I think this kind of study is good in general; as time goes on you'll get more of an intuition for what's 'natural' and what elements go together, and which wind up being stand-ins for simpler things.  I definitely do recommend studying asymptotic analysis in general as much as you can, as a lot of problems in number theory come down to studying relative rates of growth and the like.

Comment: @user243301 (I think the linked proof is a good example of this: the infinitude of squarefree pairs and even trios is proved not by providing an explicit sequence of them, but by showing that they must have positive density, from which the infinitude and even much more immediately follows.)

Comment: No please, of course isn't required apologizes, I like very much learn from my mistakes. Many thanks for your remarks and advices.